# How can I create a search method to search for name which completely matches all the other entry names

Tags: java

Don't know if the question I was asking made clear to you. So I am trying to make a method which lets me search name in my telephone directory class and finds all the entries with the same name.

//this is my method in the telephone directory class

```
public String searchEntry(Entry e) {
    if (entrylist.contains(e)) {
        return e.getSurname();
    }

    return null;

}
```

however what this method dopes is lets search for an entry and find's its extension number.

in my entry class I have got three parameters passing in the constructor

```
public Entry(String surname, String initials, String extension) {
    this.setSurname(surname);
    this.setInitials(initials);
    this.setExtension(extension);
}

    ListDirectory ls = new ListDirectory();
    Entry e = new Entry("james", "K", "9023");
    ls.addEntry(e);
    System.out.println(ls.searchEntry(e));;

//this prints out james
```

I am not sure how I could look up the names which are saved my in my telephone directory class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if I understand you correctly, but this question:

> make a method which lets me search name in my telephone directory class and finds all the entries with the same name

suggests that you want to find more than one entry, if it exists.

Consider creating a method that returns a collection of Entry items such as a `List<Entry>`, and have List (likely an `ArrayList<Entry>`) hold all the Entry items in your collection that has a matching name (last name only?).

So the method signature could look like:

```
public List<Entry> findAllMatches(String name) {
   List<Entry> entryList = new ArrayList<Entry>();

   // loop through entire collection, filling entryList

   return entryList; // this could be empty if no matches are found
}
```

If I've misinterpreted your question, then please clarify it.

Comment: Thank you. I am using an array to store everything. So I will look into it. thank you again

Answer (score 2):

If you want to search in a list for a substring or condition, you have to (unless you have a better data structure) look at each entry and check if it matches:

```
public Entry searchSubstring(String search) {
  for (Entry e : entrylist) {
    if (contains(e.getSurname(), search) || contains(e.getExtention(), search) || .. )
    {
      return e;
    }
  }
  return null; // nothing found
}

boolean contains(String haystack, String needle) {
  if (haystack == null)
    return false;

  return haystack.contains(needle);
}
```

Instead of return e, you can also do `result.add(e)` and return a list of matches.